# I can't turn on the phone or enter recovery mode (bootloop)

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, boot-loop

My Model: Alcaltel OneTouch Pop c7

My Problem: I can't seem to start the phone it is just showing the pop c7 logo and restarting itself

I can't open recovery or my turn off button + volume up, or down or both are again entering the boot loop

Any help please :\

Comment: What model number is this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a soft brick and can be fixed. You'll need SP Flashtool and flashing files for your exact model something like this: 7041x or 7041d etc.

- Download [SP Flashtool](https://spflashtool.com/)
- Download [MTK USB Drivers](https://androidmtk.com/download-mtk-usb-all-drivers) and install them.
- Download [Flash files](https://firmwarefile.com/alcatel-onetouch-pop-c7-7041d) (model 7041d) or [browse](https://firmwarefile.com/category/alcatel) all files.

See this [tutorial](https://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool) for a step by step flashing guidance.

Comment: That's impressive. I deleted my answer and up voted yours. I actually searched for a while to find a solution for this! This will definitely come in handy!